# how to solve " unsupported_grant_type "

Tags: java

my ask at bottom.

i made a web api services with uses Bearer Token Authentication, seems work fine, how did i make this decision ;

1-when i use jquery

```
var loginObject = {
                username: $("#userName").val(), // id
                password: $("#password").val(), // pass
                grant_type: "password"
            };
$.post("http://localhost:60000/getToken", loginObject, function (result) {...}
```

//results come with token.. its fine at html side thankful for jquery

2- when post with postman, still works when i use x-www-form-urlencoded.
[Works Fine Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDwZq.png)

---

BUT.. when i try post with fiddler : [Fiddler Error (400)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsZcf.png)

I GET {"error":"unsupported_grant_type"} error.

there is the error. I cant get it, i going to use this web api for my android application, when im trying to get connection with volley, same error again.

Android throw error too :
[Android Error (400)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLBuO.png)

I'am asking for you, how can i solve this problem. thanks all.

---

before create this question, i looked almost all error question like this. everyone just sayin : put the "content-type: app/x-ww..." , you can see i put this.

---

PHOTOS UPDATE :

1- Works Fine Picture 1 (Postman(app/x-www-form-urlencoded)) :https://ibb.co/dzZf29

2- Fiddler Error (400) : https://ibb.co/gomGaU

3- Android Error (400) : https://ibb.co/gi8UvU

(Add) 4- Postman (raw) (400) : http://prntscr.com/ktkl5b

the last add photo you can see, even postman the raw option, gives this error.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs only in Fiddler which means the problem is the way you are passing the data on it. Instead of passing and object try putting the data in the request body as an URL:

```
grantType=password&username=admin&password=123
```

Comment: unfortunately not work,

by the way this error come up, android and also postman(raw option) too same error. picture : http://prntscr.com/ktkjb8

Comment: That's the way you are doing it... If in postman you want to use Raw option, the body should have the data as an URL, not as an object: `grantType=password&username=admin&password=123`